# While updating the Kotlin version from 1.7.10 to 1.9.10 Multiple test cases are failing

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, kotlin-coroutines, mockk

### Issue Description

After updating the Kotlin version from 1.7.10 to 1.9.10, multiple tests are failing, and the primary issue is indicated by the error message:

```
kotlinx.coroutines.test.UncaughtExceptionsBeforeTest: There were uncaught exceptions before the test started. Please avoid this, as such exceptions are also reported in a platform-dependent manner so that they are not lost.
kotlinx.coroutines.test.UncaughtExceptionsBeforeTest: There were uncaught exceptions before the test started. Please avoid this, as such exceptions are also reported in a platform-dependent manner so that they are not lost.
at app//kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestScopeImpl.enter(TestScope.kt:242)
at app//kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt.runTest-8Mi8wO0(TestBuilders.kt:307)
at app//kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runTest-8Mi8wO0(Unknown Source)
at app//kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt.runTest-8Mi8wO0(TestBuilders.kt:166)
at app//kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runTest-8Mi8wO0(Unknown Source)
at app//kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt.runTest-8Mi8wO0$default(TestBuilders.kt:158)
at app//kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runTest-8Mi8wO0$default(Unknown Source)

Below are the mocking lib versions
- Mockk version -  1.13.8
- Mockito version - 5.6.0
- org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test - 1.7.3
```

Comment: I am curious to know why you use Mockito, while you are using Mokk. Can you update your post by including the failing tests?

Comment: add the failing tests

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this, we can write our own global uncaught exception handler and re throw the exception to JVM to handle it

```
class RethrowingExceptionHandler : TestRule, Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
    override fun uncaughtException(
        thread: Thread,
        throwable: Throwable
    ): Nothing = throw UncaughtException(throwable)

    override fun apply(base: Statement, description: Description): Statement {
        return object : Statement() {
            @Throws(Throwable::class)
            override fun evaluate() {
            }
        }
    }
}

internal class UncaughtException(cause: Throwable) : Exception(cause)
```

Also to add the rule in the test class

```
@get:Rule
    val throwRule = RethrowingExceptionHandler()
```

Comment: think i need a little detail about the reason for usint the retrowing exception handler... did u have a similas scenario?